# Apparent contradiction in relativistic velocity addition

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Suppose we have standard configuration.

It is easy to see that $\beta\rightarrow 1$ implies that

$$u=\frac{u’+v}{1+\frac{u’v}{c^2}}\rightarrow c$$

However,

$$u’=\frac{u-v}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}}\rightarrow -c$$

Where have I gone wrong? Shouldn’t both give $c$?

Comment: Why is this a contradiction? Maybe you should clearly identify what you think $u$, $u'$, $v$, and $\beta$ represent and why you think this is a contradiction

Comment: Oh, I forgot that making the unknown variable $u’$ implies that I should consider the observer being in the frame $O’$ instead. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Indeed speed is a vector, so changing reference frames - changes vector sign too. In addition to that special relativity doesn't forbids any particular speed of light direction, only talks about maximum possible magnitude.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I think this would, perhaps with some further elaboration, perfectly qualify as an answer.